# Change State Income Tax

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, moving

During 2020, my permanent address from January 2020 to August 2020 was in New York City. From September 2020 to December 2020, my permanent address was in Pennsylvania. Here are some notes:

1. From January 2020 to August 2020 I was staying in hotels in New Jersey.
2. From August 2020 to December 2020 I was staying in an Airbnb in New Jersey

So basically I was staying in New Jersey all of 2020 but technically my permanent address was NY (from January 2020 to August 2020) and PA (from September 2020 to December 2020).

Is this incorrect? Should I only file state returns for NJ?

Information from the comments:

> Q: Did you perform your work in the hotel rooms/AirBnB in New Jersey?
> Or did you perform your work at an office in New York/Pennsylvania?
>
> A:hotel rooms/airbnb in New Jersey

Comment: did your employer collect any state income taxes for NY or Pennsylvania? How did you establish your permanent address as NY or PA?

Comment: All three of these states will have rules related to residency, you'll need to look through those rules and determine where you will owe taxes then whether or not any of the states will let you offset for the tax payments to the other state(s)

Comment: ... and worst case, you have to file in all three and pay in all three. Don't expect them to agree on rules or make it fair to you.

Comment: @quid: When there is income doubly taxed by two states, you can always claim a credit in one of them.

Comment: @taxjuywewe: Did you perform your work in the hotel rooms/AirBnB in New Jersey? Or did you perform your work at an office in New York/Pennsylvania?

Comment: @user102008: hotel rooms/airbnb in New Jersey

Comment: @user102008, that could be true.  I doubt it's 100% of the time always true, and the rules certainly aren't the same between all 50 states etc.  So this person needs to understand residency in the three states and when income it taxable and which states will allow credits.

Comment: @taxguywewe: Do you know if you will be considered a tax resident of NY, NJ, and/or PA, for all or part of the year? And if so, which parts?